# excel data filter

Tags: excel, graph, excel-2007

I have a csv file open in excel. I want to create two line graphs by choosing two rows. The problem is that these rows are in one row. How is this possible? One row contains many values from which a set of values needs to be plotted against set of values in the same row. The power of the two sets are identical. These two sets of values are fetched by filtering the row according to the values of other columns. I can create the plot of one set since I can apply the filter once. How can I add the second set of values onto the existing plot by doing an independent filter on the same column? I don't want to split the file into two different files. I am not that familiar with excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is labeled, you probably want to use a [pivot chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-pivottable-and-pivotchart-reports-HP010177384.aspx). Click the link for an overview